# Using grep with regular expression to filter out matches

Tags: grep

I'm trying to use grep with -v for invert-match along with -e for regular expression.  I'm having trouble getting the syntax right.

I'm trying something like

```
tail -f logFile | grep -ve "string one|string two"
```

If I do it this way it doesn't filter
If I change it to

```
tail -f logFile | grep -ev "string one|string two"
```

I get

```
grep: string one|string two: No such file or directory
```

I have tried using () or quotes, but haven't been able to find anything that works.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The problem is that by default, you need to escape your |'s to get proper alternation.  That is, grep interprets "foo|bar" as matching the literal string "foo|bar" only, whereas the pattern "foo\|bar" (with an escaped |) matches either "foo" or "bar".

To change this behavior, use the -E flag:

```
tail -f logFile | grep -vE 'string one|string two'
```

Alternatively, use egrep, which is equivalent to grep -E:

```
tail -f logFile | egrep -v 'string one|string two'
```

Also, the -e is optional, unless your pattern begins with a literal hyphen.  grep automatically takes the first non-option argument as the pattern.

Comment: heh, learn something new every day, I never noticed the -E flag on grep before.

Comment: does this solution works for `MacOS`? I try `history | grep -vE 'ng|npm'` but it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @Sergii: Yes, the version of grep included with macOS (BSD grep) fully supports the `-v` and `-E` flags.  "Doesn't work" is a vague description, you'll have to provide more details.  I suggest you ask a new question, rather than post in the comments here.

Answer (score 7):

You need to escape the pipe symbol when -e is used:

```
tail -f logFile | grep -ve "string one\|string two"
```

EDIT: or, as [@Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364105/using-grep-with-regular-expression-to-filter-out-matches#364113) pointed out, you can use the -E flag:

```
tail -f logFile | grep -vE "string one|string two"
```

Comment: I tested the first part on my system and it had the desired results. Not sure what you mean by inaccurate.