# remove multiple lines from text file using grep

Tags: grep

I would like to remove unwanted lines from my text file had certain words. i have use grep -v like this

```
grep -v 'error|fault|unkownn' input.txt > out.txt
```

it's working with one word but not on multiple words. did i miss anything?

Comment: I think this was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364105/using-grep-with-regular-expression-to-filter-out-matches , wasn't it?

Comment: @jstarek you are right, I have searched for 1 hour SO but couldn't find it, I don't know why it's hide from me :). thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`|` is only treated as a a regex character when `grep` is working in *extended* regex mode.  So you need to do one of the following:

```
# Escape the | so that it's treated as a regex control character
grep -v 'error\|fault\|unkownn' input.txt > out.txt

# -E enables extended regex mode
grep -vE 'error|fault|unkownn' input.txt > out.txt

# egrep = grep -E
egrep -v 'error|fault|unkownn' input.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverflow**. Please remember to accept the answer that best solves your problem, if any, by pressing the [checkmark sign](http://i.imgur.com/uqJeW.png). When you see good Q&A, vote them up by using the [gray triangles](http://i.imgur.com/kygEP.png). Note that `giving` reputation points to others does not mean a deduction to your reputation points (unless you have posted a bounty)